# flight connection, airlink, or connecting flight?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

If you want to know if there are flights from airport A to airport B, what do you ask?

-Are there flight connections between airport A and B?

-Are there airlinks between airport A and B?

-Are there connecting flights between airport A and B?

What is the best word?

Comment: Why not just "Are there any flights from airport A to airport B?" Generally, when you ask about a connecting flight, it would be a single point. For example, "I want to fly from New York to San Franciso. Are there any connecting flights through Houston?"

Comment: “Airlink”?  Huh?

Comment: I agree. By asking simply 'are there any flights from Airport A to Airport B?' the question appears to be answered before it got off the ground!

Comment: @TonyBalmforth "got off the ground" - appropriate wording!

Answer (score 2):

One would typically ask, "Are there any *direct flights* between A and B? If there are no direct flights it may still be possible to fly from A to B via some other city. In which case it may be described as a flight from A to B *with a connection in* C. Or sometimes simply "I've got a flight from Phoenix to Detroit *through* Pittsburgh."

Comment: This explains it rather well.  As for when to use the word _connection_, the number of _connections_ (which is short for _connecting flights_) is one less than the total number of flights.  Washington to Atlanta to Denver to Ogden is three total flights, or one flight with two connections (and also one brutal travel day).

Comment: -1. A *direct* flight is a single flight number between two points with intermediate stops. A *nonstop* flight has no intermediate stops. There are significant differences between the two for things like frequent flyer mileage and segment accrual, fare construction, and fare and upgrade availability, and the terminology is absolutely not interchangeable if you are interacting with an airline or anyone in the travel industry.

Comment: @choster- Having looked at Wikipedia, I will acknowledge that it appears to agree with you, but I have never in my life heard of that distinction and I disagree wholeheartedly with it.  If an airplane lands anywhere but my intended destination, it did not go there *directly*.  So I will continue to call a *non-stop* and a direct flight equivalent.  I have never gotten into trouble doing so and I don't anticipate any in the future, but thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @choster: I applaud you detecting and making the distinction, which also flew over my head, but I still think the -1 is harsh. Say I asked a travel agent to book a direct flight between two cities, and the plane made an intermediate stop.  If I asked the travel agent about this later, and the agent told me, "You didn't ask for a _non-stop_ flight, you asked for a _direct_ flight.  You never had to change planes, did you?" then I'd be miffed and would probably never work with that travel agent again. This may be one of those cases where language between the layman and the specialist differs.

Comment: @J.R. A responsible travel agent would confirm, "By direct, do you mean non-stop?" As I noted the distinction has significant consequences, especially for international travel where taking a technical stop can add hours of travel time yet forfeit thousands of qualifying miles, and it is irresponsible ever to advise someone to say *direct* when *nonstop* is intended.

Comment: @choster: Of course you're right, so I'm not arguing, but I thought we could at least share a chuckle over [this](http://froschinsider.com/so-what-is-a-direct-flight-anyway/). Congrats ~ sticker for you! :^)